# How to backup and restore only one cube in SSAS database

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, ssas-2008

I have a cube in a test environment which is in an SSAS database with other non-related cubes. Since I'm testing my ETL and Fact table, I need to truncate the Fact and re-run the ETL and cube multiple times but I need to have backups of previous versions of the cube.

I can't backup the whole database because the other cubes are huge. Is there any other way for this? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can script the Cube, run the script on the other server and then process it separately.